# How to get source object from DocumentListener (DocumentEvent)?

Tags: java, swing, documentlistener

I have my class and I have implemented `DocumentListener`

```
public void removeUpdate( DocumentEvent arg0 ) {
   System.out.println( arg0.getDocument());
}
```

It would print `javax.swing.text.PlainDocument@49ea903c`

Is there any possible way I would get the object so I can get the value of the changed textfield? At the moment I have only one field so I do not need a check, but what if I use two or more, how do I know which `JTextField` has notified the listener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to get the swing component from a Document. But the issue is easily solved: just add a different instance of the listener to every text field, and store the text field in the listener itself.

```
textField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener(textField1));
textField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener(textField2));
textField3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener(textField3));
```

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that, I was hoping I could make my code cleaner, like you can use event.getSource() on ActionListener.. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Found any nice alternatives yet?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use an inner class, which will provide you an opportunity to reference the text field.

```
final JTextField field = new JTextField();

field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  // Here you can reference 'field' in your methods
});
```

If you need to perform the same action for each text field, [JB Nizet's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16626369/474189) will be neater.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are getting the `PlainDocument` object. Just store it in a variable instead of printing it.

For more info see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/PlainDocument.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is adding document listners to each component you need.If you really need to know which text fields text has changed then you can have a property in the DocumentListner as textFieldName or something and you can set it when you create the document listner for them.But I think you better change your approaching to situation.It doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 0):

You may update the document without knowing the context.

Consult the documentation of [javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html)

- [javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.getOffset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html#getOffset%28%29) Returns the offset within the document of the start of the change.
- [javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.getLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html#getLength%28%29) Returns the length of the change.

These methods combined with the document retrieved by [javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.getDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentEvent.html#getDocument%28%29) allow you to update the document in a proper way. Later you may add other text field without any change.

To simply get the text of a JTextField after change:

```
JTextField myTf = new ...; // maybe an attribute definition
...
myTf.addActionListener(
   new ActionListener(){@Override public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
      JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
      System.out.println( tf.getText());
      if( tf == myTf ) { // == for reference comparison
         ... // do something dedicated to myTf
      }
   }});
```

Comment: I have gone through the documentation several times before I have asked my question here, but I do not see how getOffset() or getLenght() is helping me. I want to get the text in the field after the change, not the length as I will do a search based on that

Comment: DocumentListener is used for more complex action, see my edit